# c# how to determine full path of file opened

Tags: c#, file, excel, ms-office

I am programming an excel add in, and I want to be able to determine the full path of the current excel file open.  What would the command be to get this as a string?

Thank You!

Comment: Do you get any path for the file that has been opened? If so, can you give an example of what that might look like, and what you would like instead?

Comment: for example: if the file newBook.xls is opened and it is located in My Documents.  I want a function that returns a string: User/MyDocuments/newBook.xls

Comment: Yeah, but do you get a path from an opened document at all? Not *just* examples of what you'd like. Also, the *full* path, wouldn't that be C:\Users\SomeUser\...\Documents\newBook.xls?

Comment: I am not sure of the command to do this but yes I would want: C:\user\someuser...

Comment: Try posting an example of what code you have so we have something more concrete to work on

Comment: You should use `Workbook.FullName` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to somehow get a `Workbook` exemplar. My example would be obvious, because I've already know where is my file, but if you getting `Workbook` passed to you from somewhere you can use the same property.

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
string workbookPath = "c:/SomeWorkBook.xls";
Excel.Workbook openedWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
            0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
            true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

Now you can use `FullName` property to get name of file and all preceding path, or simply "Name" to get only filename: `openedWorkbook.FullName`